# Emailing out an item in sharepoint 2010 to users that don't have access to the site

Tags: sharepoint, email

I am trying to figure out how to email out one item from a list by when you have an item clicking on a button as a web part.  Sort of like when you create a print button and it prints out just the one item.

I don't want all of my users to have to download anything.  Is there a way just to code the webpart to create a button where your outlook email pops up with a new email and the list item and details are in the body of the email?

Comment: Here is the code I am using currently:   <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Contact Us" onClick="parent.location='mailto:you@youremail.com?subject=The subject you want to appear&body=NEED TO HAVE PICTURE OF ITEM HERE">

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to build a button that would use JavaScript to scrape the contents of a specific element on a page (since you are building client side script) and put them into the body of an email, there's a lot of formatting issues that can arise there since non-text elements might be lost, styling might drop off and there's the potential for XSS, etc. You would also have to edit the item template for that button to show up.

You can also build a custom action that sends the content of the item through email with a workflow. This requires a bit of dev work in SharePoint that you may or may not be familiar with.

Additionally, if they don't have access to that site, why would you automate sending them content from it? If it's content they should have access to, why not put it in a list/library that is more tailored to their permission level?